# Google cloud Platform vpn creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

I am trying to create VPN for the first time on GCP. But I am getting this error. Please help.

Create VPN "vpn-1"

My First Project
Failed validation of TunnelMetadata REGION:1000/PROJECT:618306885804/VPN_TUNNEL:7554278315356445334: * peer_ip may not be in RFC1918 IP range: 10.128.0.1

Comment: Did you research this error? Do you understand RFC1918 addressing? You specified an invalid IP address for the VPN tunnel. Your question does not have details on how you configured the VPN, the router involved, how the router is configured, etc.

Comment: Actually, I am very new to this. I am just trying this for the first time.  Will try to know more about RFC1918. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, here is a little summary about the RFC1918:

RFC1918 name    IP address range    Classful description

24-bit block    10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255   single class A network

20-bit block    172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 16 contiguous class B networks

16-bit block    192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255   256 contiguous class C networks

So, once that this has been clarified, when you are configuring a VPN, you need to have peer-A and peer-B, these Peers (A and B) should be Public IP Addresses (Non RFC1918), as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-static-vpns#creating_a_gateway_and_tunnel) "Remote peer IP address — Specify the external IP address of the peer VPN gateway."

Here you have an example about how to configure a [VPN Tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-static-vpns), please if you have any further comments, don't hesitate to let me know it.